# Google ReCaptch [invalid-input-response] error

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, invisible-recaptcha

So we are using google ReCaptcha in our site, but for one country it's returning as [invalid-input-response] error, but for the same code flow for another site it's working fine.
I saw others also raised this similar issue but there are no responses, also google ReCaptcha support mail is also invalid in their support site. I hope I get some solution/response to my query here.
I checked the site key and the secret key and they are correct.
Again I repeat, this code worked perfectly.
What can be causing this issue?

Any kind of response is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This invalid-input-response-error is caused when the google recaptcha response that you are sending from client browser to google api for verification is not proper one. it might be empty or tampered before sending.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** From what I saw and tested from this link -> https://groups.google.com/g/recaptcha/c/yEPN3d9ylT8 in Cyber's comment, the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER was the differentiator. But in my case I didn't need to add the IP for that.

---

My test using PHP. This is my code that worked.

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$secret = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY";
$reponse = $request['g-recaptcha-response'];
$variaveis = "secret=".$secret."&response=". $reponse;

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$variaveis);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($variaveis)));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$resposta = curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, and even following the [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) exactly, was still getting this error.

One potential fix which worked for me that's easy to try out is to make a new site on the [Google reCAPTCHA dashboard](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin) and see if the issue persists with a different set of public/secret keys. For some reason my original keys stopped working and the only indicator was having this "invalid-input-response" error show up.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this kind of error by very dummy mistake by accidentaly sending content of the message in the captcha post.
I will just leave it here if anybody will be searching for error faster than debugging and checking their data before actually sending it further in the code.

Explanation what I had there:

Wrong:

```
                "content":$('textarea[name="content"]').val(),
                "g-recaptcha-response":$('textarea[name="content"]').val()},
```

Corrected:

```
                "content":$('textarea[name="content"]').val(),
                "g-recaptcha-response":$('textarea[id="g-recaptcha-response"]').val()},
```