# How to integrate Google Recaptcha V3 in php

Tags: php, forms, google-api, captcha, recaptcha-v3

I have this error that i have been trying to fix

here's the problem:

```
{
  error-codes:['invalid-input-response']
  success:false
}
```

My current PHP code is:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Process the form submission
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Verify reCAPTCHA v3
    $secretKey = 'my_secret_key'; // this one i will replace it, this is just to show you the code
    $recaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    echo '<script>console.log("' . $recaptchaResponse . '")</script>';

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = [
        'secret' => $secretKey,
        'response' => $recaptchaResponse,
    ];

    $options = [
        'http' => [
            'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ],
    ];

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $result = json_decode($response, true);
    echo '<script>console.log(' . $response . ')</script>';
    if ($response === false) { 
        echo "Failed to contact the reCAPTCHA service.";
    } else {

        if ($result['success']) { 
            $to = "info@example.com"; // just for test
            $subject = "Contact Form Submission";
            $headers = "From: info@example.com"; // just for test

            $body = "Name: $name\nCompany: $company\nPhone: $phone\nEmail: $email\nMessage: $message";

            // Send the email
            if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                echo "<script>alert('Email sent successfully!')</script>";
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('Failed to send email.')</script>";
            }
        } else {
            // reCAPTCHA v3 verification failed
            echo "<script>alert('reCAPTCHA verification failed. Please try again.')</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70061153/google-recaptch-invalid-input-response-error

Comment: Can you try with cURL instead?

Comment: How i can do that? i have no idea about it

Comment: @Mr-montasir Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-and-http-post-example I am suggesting cURL because I see no explicit advantage of stream_context_create over cURL.